# How to avoid $oid in response of get by id in mongodb with java?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, dbobject

When performing the following code

```
    JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject();
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(mongoip, mongoport);
            DB db = mongo.getDB(mongodb);

            DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("abc");
            query = new BasicDBObject();
            query.put("_id", new ObjectId(recordID));
            dbObj = collection.findOne(query);

            JSONObject output = new JSONObject(JSON.serialize(dbObj));

                                        jSONObject.put("data", output);
                res = jSONObject.toString();
    return res;
```

I am getting this response:

```
data {
  "_id":{"$oid":"5c90bc4c32ef32622181d86b"},
  "created_at":"2019-03-19 03:24:20",
  "updated_at":"2019-03-19 03:33:40",
  "Temp":"30",
  "Oil":"60",
  "test":"123"
}
```

But i don't want `$oid` in response, I want response like this:

```
data {
  "_id":"5c90bc4c32ef32622181d86b",
  "created_at":"2019-03-19 03:24:20",
  "updated_at":"2019-03-19 03:33:40",
  "Temp":"30",
  "Oil":"60",
  "test":"123"
}
```

Please help me getting response like this. What should i do?

Comment: It is representing ObjectId. You don't worry about it. If you want it as string you must convert to string.

Comment: It is in string only. I don't want this seperate {"$oid":"5c90bc4c32ef32622181d86b"} in response.As i mentioned i want response like that.Please help me regarding that.